# Why getting Error accessing Cassandra with DataStax ODBC Driver?

Tags: odbc, cassandra

We are using Cassandra 2.2.11, and trying to configure DataStax ODBC driver. We are getting the following error message:

> SQLSTATE: HY000[DataStax][CassandraODBC] (10) Error while executing a query in Cassandra: [33554688] : Received error response 'Username and/ or password are incorrect' (0x02000100)

Comment: You need to specify correct user name and password when connecting. Check that they are working in `cqlsh`

Comment: I've already test the connection with cqlsh, from another host, and works. But, just a minute ago, we reinstalled the driver, and the connection worked fine. Thanks for yor reply.